# carthage bootstrap fails because of parallel git processes accessing shared cache index.lock file

Tags: ios, xcode, git, jenkins, carthage

I'm triggering **multiple iOS builds in parallel** from Jenkins on a Jenkins slave.
When the build triggers the below command I get an error.

**Command**

```
carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries --platform ios --use-ssh --cache-builds
```

**Output**

```
2020-01-29 21:34:58.471 carthage[85379:2625480] INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file /Users/user/Library/Caches/carthage/fsCachedData/7A4CE621-0AC6-4FAF-B0CE-33FDD32A0113. Errno: 2
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.8.2"
*** Checking out ios-client at "3.0.0"
*** Checking out stripe-ios at "v18.3.0"
*** Checking out swift-protobuf at "1.5.0"
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git checkout --quiet --force v18.3.0 (launched in /Users/user/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/stripe-ios)) failed with exit code 128:
fatal: Unable to create '/Users/user/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/stripe-ios/./index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

make: *** [carthage-install] Error 1
```

How can this issue be fixed? I guess this happens because multiple processes are trying to access the shared Carthage cache.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this issue in the Carthage repository? Seems like it describes the problem you are having: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1187

The issue is that Carthage was never intended to be run in parallel since it uses locks that can hang if multiple Carthage jobs run as the same user. If you configure your CI machine to have multiple users, where one Carthage job runs for each user, this problem should not occur. If you have one user logged in automatically when the machine starts where that user starts multiple build agents, and those agents can overlap in their Carthage activity, builds can fail in the way you describe.

There is a fork of Carthage that claims to have addressed this problem: https://github.com/nsoperations/Carthage - I have not tried it yet but think I will. If you are stuck using Carthage, and you want your Mac CI machine to recover from power loss to a state where multiple build agents (e.g. for Buildkite) are running I think it might be the only answer. If I knew a reliable way to cause multiple users to become logged in automatically, with agent processes started by each as they become logged in, that would make continuing to use the main branch of Carthage possible.